# How to get source of html page from a https adress in java

Tags: java, rapidshare

I am trying to implement a download manager in java for rapidshare, I am using the rapidshare API.
The problem is that for example if you go to the following [link](http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=download&fileid=3475274567&filename=ERKA_0413_HRALinks.info.avi)
it redirects to a https page, but then when I read the content it always return me null in the InputStream
When I try to put a https link in the HttpURLConnection it always throws an exeption

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path     validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
```

Comment: Have you tried using its direct subclass, javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection?

Comment: yes I tried the HttpsURLConnection, but still the same

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache Commons HTTPUtils .  You can make a connection to HTTPS (thereby decrypting it) if you override the DefaultTrustManager class (to do nothing), create a new TrustManager with it, then bypass the hostname verifier with ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER.   Since your opening the connection to a place that you trust, there isn't a problem bypassing these things.